# problem in installation on acts_as_taggable_on_steroids as a gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

hi  i am trying to use acts_as_taggable_on_steroids in my rails3 project, but it gives me error.Once i installed it as plugin but no improvement.

please give me steps to install it as gem in rails3 ,and it's usage.

Comment: Can you please let us know what error you are getting?

Comment: when i run migration for it tables were not created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use it as a plugin to work, at least that way worked for me in Rails 3. Download the plugin and put in in /vendor/plugins folder in your project.